# php: zipping a csv does work on localhost (xampp) but not on production server

Tags: php, csv

I have this `php` function:

```
function get_partij_download_new($dbmi, $partij) {      
    set_time_limit(0);
    $stmt = $dbmi->prepare("CALL spStartPartijDownload(?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $partij);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $headers = array('id', 'zorgverlener', 'zorgverlener_type', 'jaar', 'id_contractpartij', 'contractpartij',
    'dc_code', 'dc_oms', 'tt_oms', 'zp_code', 'zp_oms', 'zpg_oms', 'tarief');
    $fp = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:999999999999', 'w');
    if ($fp && $result) {
        $zipname = 'export_tarvieven_contractpartij.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        fputcsv($fp, $headers, ";");
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          fputcsv($fp, $row, ";");
        }
        rewind($fp);
        $zip->addFromString('export_tarieven.csv', stream_get_contents($fp) );
        fclose($fp);
        $zip->close();
    }
    $stmt->close();   
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
    readfile($zipname);
    unlink($zipname);
}
```

When I run this on my localhost (xampp version 5.6.19) it works OK and gives me a zip that contains the expected `csv` file. When I run the exact same function on the production server (`php` version >7) it still creates the zip file but the zip doesn't contain the `csv`, it's empty..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a memory problem. Try to use `php://temp` without `maxmemory`:

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w');
```